# Copying files from multiple folder to another folder

Tags: python, copy

I have a folder called Reports with multiple folders ID1, ID2, ID3...and so on.
Each of these folders have a json report. Now I want to copy all these json reports into a single folder called Input

```
import os 
import sys
import shutil
list={} 
list=os.system("find /home/admin1/Report -name '*.json'")
print list
for i in list:
    os.system('cp i /home/admin1/Input')
```

This gives error:
    TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: use `os` or `glob` module to get a list of dirs. with json

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few issues here.

1. You're redefining Python's builtin `list` function, and defining it as a variable, containing an empty dictionary (which is not even a list).
2. You then throw away that empty dictionary and redefine `list` as the result of `os.system("find /home/admin1/Report -name '*.json'")`. That's not gonig to do what you want, because `os.system` returns an integer (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). It looks like you were expecting it to return a list of results.
3. You're then trying to use the `for` loop to iterate over that integer, which is what's giving you the `TypeError`.
4. `os.system('cp i /home/admin1/Input')` (which your program never gets to due to the error above) literally runs `cp i /home/admin1/Input`, you're not substituting `"i"` for the value of variable `i`.

Rather than using os.system to run `find`, it would arguably be better to use Python's `os.walk` (see https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-traverse-a-directory-tree-in-python-guide-to-os-walk/) to work through the directory tree yourself, rather than trying to manually parse the output of `find`.